# Dspring.profiles.active value difference between 'prod' and 'default'?

Tags: spring, grpc, spring-profiles

I'm connecting a Web server to a backend using gRPC services.

In the case of backend being set up with `-Dspring.profiles.active=default`, the gRPC api connects but using `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` the connection times out.

In the code, there is no setups for neither value so I'm left to presume they are profile that come "out of the box" with Spring!?

Thats the hypothesis at least cause there doesn't seem to be any other setup and deployment differences that might be causing this connection errors.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The spring profile determine which `properties file` needs to be picked up while running the application.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=default  //takes the application-default.properties file

-Dspring.profiles.active= prod  //takes the application-prod.properties file
```